# Flutter just_audion : check if media file is cached

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I'm using just_audio to play and cache medias. How can I check if the media is in just_audio cache directory, before I start playing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `LockCachingAudioSource`, you can pass in the `cacheFile` parameter which is the file where you would like the audio to be cached:

```dart
final source = LockCachingAudioSource(uri, cacheFile: ...);
```

If you don't specify the `cacheFile` parameter, just_audio will decide on its own where to store this cache file, and you can obtain this file via `await source.cacheFile`.

Then testing if that cache exists is easy:

```dart
final cacheFile = await source.cacheFile;
if (await cacheFile.exists()) {
  ...
}
```